# Minimize $\sum_i |a_i + b_i x|$ over $x$

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have a set of values $v_i$ given as parameters of $x$:

$$
v_i = a_i + b_i x
$$

I would like to minimize the sum of the absolute values of $v_i$ over parameter $x$, i.e. find

$$
\arg\min_x \sum_i |a_i + b_i x|
$$

---

I assume this involves linear programming constraints, but I'm not too familiar with the subject.  I also wonder if there is a simple solution/interpretation for the problem I have presented.

Comment: @Arief, that won't give you the same solution as the question asked.  In general the sum of squares and sum of abs value do not have same minimizer, unless there is only one thing being summed.

Comment: It is an LP, if you write it as

min $\sum_i s_i$

subject to:  $a_i + b_i x \leq s_i, \forall i$

$-(a_i + b_i x) \leq -s_i, \forall i$

A number of freely available solvers should be able to handle this numerically. (Although if x is a scalar, can't you just plot it?)

Comment: You can also try lagrange multipliers. I think you might get something analytical that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimise $f(x) = \sum_i |a_i + b_i x|$, given $a_i$ and $b_i$.  First, notice $f(x)$ is differentiable for all $x$, except for $x^*$ for which $\exists i: a_i + b_i x^* = 0$.  Whenever $f$ is differentiable there is some small interval around $x$ where the function is exactly linear, in particular that $f$ is not extremised here.  So, any possible minimiser $x^*$ has $a_i + b_i x^* = 0$ for some $i$.  This means you can just check $f(x*)$ for each such $x^*$ (only finitely many to check), and evaluate which is smallest.

Comment: Ahh--thank you.  I knew vaguely how to do the linear programming mentioned above, but this answer (which seems so simple in hindsight!) is the more elegant solution I was seeking.